# Calculating the coordinate of third point in triangle

Tags: geometry

I have triangle ,where I know A coordinates (Ax,Ay), B coordinates (Bx,By) and all three angles. Now the question is : How could I calculate coordinates of C ?

Here´s the pic of  I would really appreciate your help :). Thank you

[image: triangle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1> Calculate the values of the slopes of both AC and BC.(This can be done by finding the angle AB makes with the X axis)

2> Once you get the two slopes you can express the lines AC and BC in the point slope format.

3> Solve both the line to get the meeting point.

Or if you are comfortable with translation and rotation you could shift the image such that AB is on the X axis and A is the origin. Now solve for C since tan(alpha) and tan(beta) are now slopes. Shift the value of C back. The answer is your result.

Comment: So I have AC and BC . Now ,how can i express the lines AC and BC in the point slope format :)? You know,English is not my native language,so I dont get you at all,sorry

Comment: Okay. You can get the slope of AB right; It will be  by/(bx-ax). Take tan inverse of that and you get the angle BA makes with the X axis. Now add that angle to alpha and use that to get slope of AC. Gettit.

Comment: So, arctan(by/(bx-ax)). That sould be done :D... Now,I should do this? Alpha + answer ? And I can´t shift image, cause I am actually programming it :/

Comment: Yea. You understand why tan(alpha  +answer) is the slope for AC right?

Comment: not at all... and if i will want to calculate the BC slope? will it be arctan(ay/(ax-bx))+beta ?And if i have these slopes, answers are the coordinations of C ?

Comment: tan($\alpha$ + angle ) is the slope for AC since $\alpha$+angle is the angle that it makes with the X axis.

Comment: so, slope for BC will be tan(beta+angle) :) ? and how could I calculate second angle ?

Comment: Extend CB such that it meets the X axis at D. Now you know $\angle$ ACD and $\angle$ CAD. Using them you can find $\angle$ ADC. $\tan(\angle ADC)$ will the negative of the slope for BC.

Comment: I am affraid,that I won´t be able to do it,because, as I said before, I am making program of it and I can´t imagine, how could i make it,you know. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to click on the link but here are some hints on how to go about it.

- What angle does $\overline{AB}$ make with the $x$ axis?  (Hint: it involves the slope.)
- Since you know the angles, you can determine what angles $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$ make with the $x$ axis by adding (or subtracting) them from the angle you found above.
- You can use these angles to find the slopes of the sides, and then equations for the lines that define the sides (using point-slope form).
- Then, solve for the common solution of those two lines, which will be point $C$.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to resolve BC slope :)?

Comment: The angle $AB$ makes with the $x$ axis is $\text{arctan}(\Delta y / \Delta x)$.  Since you're interested in the slope of $BC$, add $\pi$ to the angle you get (so it's like a vector pointing down and to the left).  Whether you do this part or not depends on the particular values of the points; the line may slope the other way.  Then subtract $\beta$ from that angle, and take the tangent.  That will be the slope of $BC$.

Comment: So if I got you right : (arctan( (by-ay)/(bx-ax) ) + pi) - beta and tangent of whole this number will be slope of BC ?

Comment: Right.  Just make sure $\beta$ is in radians.

Comment: Great point,I have it converted. And for AC it will be like this,right ? (arctan(by/(bx-ax)) + alfa)